# Can't enable IIS logging without using the GUI

Tags: iis, logging, webserver, iis-8

IIS logging has been disable via the GUI:
[image]

I just want to enable it, but apparently this is impossible without using the GUI.

Commands I have tried:

```
appcmd set config /section:httpLogging /dontLog:False /selectiveLogging:LogAll

Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\MySite" -name logFile -value @{enabled=$true}

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='MySite']/logFile" -name "LogExtFileFlags" -value @{enabled=$true}
```

When I do a Get-Windowsfeature I can see IIS-HttpLogging is marked as enabled.

Nothing I have tried has enabled IIS logging, I have to use the GUI and click enable.

When I run this it returns true:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv> (Get-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/MYSite" ).logfile.enabled
```

Edit:
So logging *seems* to work even though the GUI displays it as "disabled". Perhaps this is a bug in the GUI?

Edit2: 
OK so if I try the appcmd command and target my specific site I get this error:

```
.\appcmd set config "MySite" /section:httpLogging /dontLog:False

PS C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv> .\appcmd set config "MySite" /section:httpLogging /dontLog:False
ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "dontLog" to value "False".. Reason: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false
```

Is says the section is locked at the parent level, but I was able to click enable for the site's logging in the GUI and did not get any errors.

Comment: Please spend some time on IIS configuration schema and see how many "enabled" are there. You simply hit the wrong ones and misunderstand. The "siteDefaults" is only used when a new site is created, and each sites then uses their own tags.

Comment: Even when I do it to the specific site I can still see the site config says its enabled, but in the GUI it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote the clone of IIS Manager, I can tell you the "Enable/Disable" button links to an attribute called "dontLog", https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager.Features.Logging/LoggingFeature.cs

Its reference can be found at

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httplogging